# 'if' statement logic with a 'where' condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, if-statement, where-clause

I am trying to display a single image from a list of products that belong to a particular category. example I wish to display one food product, one household product, one clothing product etc...
each product has a field that is filled in with a drop down menu that dictates what category it belongs to.
I've implemented the following logic in the controller

```
if Product.where(:department.eql? "Stationery") then
  @stationery = [Product.where(:department.eql? "Stationery").first]
end
if Product.where(:department.eql? "Food") then
  @food = [Product.where(:department.eql? "Food").first]
end
if Product.where(:department.eql? "Toiletries") then
  @toiletries = [Product.where(:department.eql? "Toiletries").first]
end
if Product.where(:department.eql? "Household") then
  @household = [Product.where(:department.eql? "Household").first]
end
if Product.where(:department.eql? "Clothing") then
  @clothing = [Product.where(:department.eql? "Clothing").first]
end
if Product.where(:department.eql? "Accessories") then
  @accessories = [Product.where(:department.eql? "Accessories").first]
end
```

and In the view I have this

```
<% @stationery.each do |stationery| %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <% if Product.where(:department.eql? 'Stationery') %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(stationery.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(stationery.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% @food.each do |food| %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <% if Product.where(:department.eql? 'Food') %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(food.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(food.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% @toiletries.each do |toiletries| %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <% if Product.where(:department.eql? 'Toiletries') %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(toiletries.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(toiletries.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% @household.each do |household| %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <% if Product.where(:department.eql? 'Household') %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(household.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(household.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% @clothing.each do |clothing| %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <% if Product.where(:department.eql? 'Clothing') %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(clothing.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(clothing.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% @accessories.each do |accessories| %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <% if Product.where(:department.eql? 'Accessories') %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(accessories.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(accessories.id), :controller=>'products' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

The issue I'm having is that 6 products are coming in but they are all the same product, there must be a problem with my logic here that I just can't see.

I'm aware that I've doubled up on some line here through the controller and the view but I've been messing around with this code for some time and have tried lots of variations.

my guess is that it is this line

```
 if Product.where(:department.eql? 'Household')
```

and the similar lines, but I cant figure out how to get this to work. 
Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you are doing too many "if", do you really need that many? that makes your code hard to debug.

try something like

```
@products = {}
["Stationery","Food","Toiletries","Household","Clothing","Accessories"].each do |dep|
  @products[dep] = Product.where(department: dep).first
end
```

and replace all your view with:

```
<%- ["Stationery","Food","Toiletries","Household","Clothing","Accessories"].each do |dep| -%>
  <div class="column_entry">
    <%- if product = @products[dep] -%>
      <%= link_to image_tag(product.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(product), :controller=>'products' -%>
    <%- end -%>
  </div>
<%- end -%>
```

EDIT: changed the code a little, you could even have a constant for that deparments array to be dryer

Comment: This gives me `undefined method product_image` because I don't have a `@products.each do |products|`

Comment: Where are you using that @products.each? i've eddited my code after submit, if you need to loop the @products hash do something like "@products.each do |dep, product|" since it's a hash, not an array